# Protect laravel routes with amember

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amember

I am using laravel for my web application. I have integrated amember within my larvel site inside `/publi/amember`. Now i want to protect my routes using amember. Anyone knows how to do it. I am using `L5 Moduler` structure for my larvel site.

Comment: from what i seen in the tag AMember is used as a wordpress plugin

Comment: @madalinivascu said, i searched on google and it displays results related to wordpress plugin! You are right madalinivascu!

Comment: how did you integrate AMember  in laravel exactly ?

Comment: @madalinivascu i just placed the amember files inside public and point this to my route `http://example.com/amember`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR let's assume that what you did is called "integration" why do you want to protect the laravel routes?how?from who?

Comment: @madalinivascu actually we have different types of subscription, and for each type of subscription we have different pages and functionality. So i want to need that

Comment: what does subscriptions have to do with laravel routes?

Comment: @madalinivascu actually subscriptions means to the user plans that he purchased

Comment: what does subscriptions have to do with laravel routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is use Am_Lite API to do it.
http://www.amember.com/docs/API/Lite

So you need to include this file
*amember/library/Am/Lite.php*
within your application (before any output done) and then use the following call to check access:

```
Am_Lite::getInstance()->checkAccess(Am_Lite::PAID);
```

In event of user has necessary access then this call do nothing otherwise redirect user to login form.